# SQL 'INSERT' is inserting the value multiple times instead of only one

Tags: php, sql, insert

Hello guys I was making a like system that sends to database who liked it and the content liked. But turns out that the SQL INSERT statement is doing the job more than it should... It was supposed to save a single line with the user `account_id` and the content liked that would be the `screenshot_id`. But instead, it's inserting the same value multiple times, like this:

id | account_id | screenshot_id

1 .|.........2.........|.........15...........

2 .|.........2.........|.........15...........

3 .|.........2.........|.........15...........

4 .|.........2.........|.........15...........

It was just an example, here is the actual code I'm using in php:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $acc_id = $_POST['acc_id']; //value = 2
    $id = $_POST['id']; //value = 15
    if($id && $acc_id != 0){
        $count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `id` FROM `screenshot_votes` WHERE `account_id` = '$acc_id' AND `screenshot_id` = '$id';"));
        if($count == 0){ //checking if there is already a vote with those values
            mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `screenshot_votes` (id,account_id,screenshot_id,vote) VALUES (NULL,'$acc_id','$id','2');");
        //values being insert above
        }
        $row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `vote` FROM `screenshot_votes` WHERE `screenshot_id` = $id AND `vote` = 2;"));
        echo $row;
    }
?>
```

So... How do I make this code insert the values only once like this:

id | account_id | screenshot_id

1 .|.........2.........|.........15...........

**UPDATE**

This is the onclick event in the slider jquery plugin:

```
j=function(){
var acc_id = r.accid;
e.each(o,function(t,n){
var r=e(n).children("img:first-child").attr("views");
r||(r=e(n).children("a").find("img:first-child").attr("views"));
o.on("click",".vote",function(e){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var name = $(this).attr('name');
var dataString = 'id=' + id;
if(name == 'up'){
$('.pos_value.id'+id).fadeIn(100).html('...');
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'pages/scripts/up_vote.php',
data: {id: id, acc_id: acc_id},
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$('.pos_value.id'+id).html(html);
$('.vote.pos_vote_enabled.img'+id).css({"background-image": "url(images/icons/pos.png)"});
$('.vote.pos_vote_enabled.img'+id).attr('class', 'pos_vote');
$('.vote.neg_vote_enabled.img'+id).attr('class', 'neg_vote');
}
});
}else{
$('.neg_value.id'+id).fadeIn(100).html('...');
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'pages/scripts/down_vote.php',
data: {id: id, acc_id: acc_id},
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$('.neg_value.id'+id).html(html);
$('.vote.neg_vote_enabled.img'+id).css({"background-image": "url(images/icons/neg.png)"});
$('.vote.neg_vote_enabled.img'+id).attr('class', 'neg_vote');
$('.vote.pos_vote_enabled.img'+id).attr('class', 'pos_vote');
}
});
}
return false;
});
if(r){
r=e('<span class="bjqs-views">'+r+'</span>');
r.appendTo(e(n))
}
})
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the way I posted this question in here is the right one, but if not would someone tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is the datatype of the filed `account_id` and `screenshot_id` ??

Comment: You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attack as user submitted data is being let near the database without being validated. Once user submitted data has been validated, prepared statements should be used when using it in a query.

Comment: `account_id` and `screenshot_id` are both numeric integer with length 11

Comment: the php code runs when i click on the picture, but shouldn't the `if($count == 0){ }' prevent a second insert by default?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I didn't think that would be a problem since the code runs internally with a single click, no inputs, and the account id and screenshot id are visible for users

Comment: remove quotes from valuse in select query `SELECT `id` FROM `screenshot_votes` WHERE `account_id` = $acc_id AND `screenshot_id` = $id`

Comment: thanks for the answer @Saty but I'm still getting multiple inserts with a single click I'll update the question with the on click event

Comment: yes you need to add youe onclick event

Comment: maybe I need some kind of stop after the jquery event runs so it wont execute again? If so I don't know how to do that since I'm not really used to jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I'm not sure if the rest of the script is correct but I went deeper on google for more answers and found out the `unbind()` and it worked for me putting in the onclick function:

```
o.unbind().on("click",".vote",function(e){
```